# Azure Devops and Github - both are now owned by Microsoft - which one to use?

Tags: version-control, github

Azure devops and Github, both owned by Microsoft, provides functionality of version control. Azure devops also provide task management and relative linking with commits.

My question is, if both are owned by microsoft, will both continue to stand independently or will Github merged in Devops or vice versa?

What should I pick for my repository version control?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Nobody knows.

Long answer: **It's probable** that GitHub will always be the go-to for most developers of open source projects.

DevOps and GitHub will both exist for closed source projects. However if you use the entire DevOps ecosystem it's a logical choice to also store your code there.